# Em dash to introduce a quote

Tags: academia, dashes, citation, academic-writing

Is it fine to introduce a direct quote with an em dash? I want to briefly summarise a quote, while still giving it in full. Something like:

> However, Smith (2021) argued that foo can in fact improve bar—"A common and interesting aspect of foo is that it can often improve bar".

If no - what should be done instead?

Comment: I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that I've seen. In APA, an em dash would be incorrect here. From the [APA 6th edition blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/07/punctuation-junction-punctuation-before-quotation-marks.html):

> 1. To identify the speaker of a quotation before the quotation appears, put a comma after the speaking-related verb (said, replied, stated, wrote, etc.).
> 2. To present a quotation after a complete sentence (e.g., those ending in thus or as follows), put a colon after the introductory sentence and before the quotation marks. Start the quotation that follows with a capital letter if the quotation itself is a full sentence; start the quotation with a lowercase letter if it is a sentence fragment.
> 3. For other scenarios, punctuate according to the grammar of the sentence, as though the quotation marks were not there. This means sometimes no punctuation is required before quotation marks

If you're following APA, a colon would be most appropriate. Other style guides may vary.

Comment: Wouldn't this fall under case 3, "punctuate according to the grammar of the sentence, as though the quotation marks were not there"? In the following sentence, for example, the dash is perfectly grammatical: "However, Smith (2021) argued that foo can in fact improve bar—that this was one of the most interesting aspects of foo." This is not so different from the OP's sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor I read it as you're only supposed to use #3 when the previous two don't apply. I wouldn't use an em dash in the original even without quote marks. Maybe in your quote, maybe.

Comment: I think maybe we're answering different questions. If you consider the OP to be asking the question "should I use a dash in this particular sentence," then a reasonable answer is "no, a colon is better." But if the question is "is a dash ever appropriate before a quotation," then I think the answer is definitely "yes."

Comment: To do #3 you would lower-case the A after the dash because a capital letter doesn't normally follow a dash.